# Can't bind promise data to view in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have tried the examples found on stackoverflow, but I still getting nothing in my view. I can see the articleIds  in the console but nothing in the view. Thanks you in advance for your help.

Here is my controller:

```
export class MainController {
    constructor ($http) {
        'ngInject';

        this.$http= $http;
        this.apiHost = 'http://localhost:5005/api/articles';
        this.getArticles();
    }

    getArticles() {
        var vm = this;
        this.$http.get(this.apiHost).then(function(result){
            vm.articles = result.data;
            vm.articles.forEach(function(item){
                console.log(item.articleId);
            });     
        });
    }
}
```

Here my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="resumeId">Select article:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="resumeId">
    <option ng-repeat="item in main.vm.articles" value="{{item.articleId}}">{{item.articleId }}</option>
  </select></div>
```

Comment: I add main.vm.articles because the route use controllerAs: 'main'

Comment: Have you tried `ng-repeat="item in articles"`? From what I can tell that should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! ng-repeat="item in main.articles" works

Comment: I'll add that as an answer in the interest of marking this question as resolved. Feel free to approve the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the promise, the HTML just references the wrong scope. In the $http callback you assign the result to `vm.articles` (where `vm` is the controller's scope), so `articles` is available at `main.articles` rather than `main.vm.articles`.

Change your `ng-repeat` to `ng-repeat="item in main.articles"` and it will work.

Comment: Not (vm == this), just change the code to ng-repeat="item in main.articles"

Comment: What I was trying to explain is that `vm` is the controller's scope. Have updated the question to improve this.